# C# How to make an x and y array change based on eachother array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# programming and I'm having this problem. I'll try to explain as best as I can:

let's say I have an X array that has[ 9, 2 , 4 ]
and I have an Y array containing [ 7, 5, 3 ].

I want to "link" these so when I change the X array the Y array follows it.

e.g. I sort the X array to: [ 2, 4, 9 ] and so the Y array becomes [ 5, 3, 7 ]

since in the X array 2 was "linked" to 5 in the Y array and so on.

What I want to know is if it's possible to "link" these arrays so that when I sort X, Y changes the positions of it's numbers according to how I changed X.
(And the other way around)

Sorry if worded the question wrong, I couldn't think of another way to word it.

Comment: theres nothing built in like that. you should try to code something first.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a bimap. What you're describing is less constrained though.

Comment: Could you simply define an object that held x and y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggesting *zipping* both arrays into one `Z`:

```
   using System.Linq;
   ...

   // Tuple<int, int> - just a pair of two int values
   // a custom class to hold x, y values is a better design
   var Z = X
     .Zip(Y, (x, y) => new Tuple<int, int>(x, y))
     .OrderBy(item => item.Item1)  // let's sort by x
     .ThenBy(item => item.Item2)   // in case of tie by y
     .ToList();                    // or .ToArray()
```

whenever you want `X` or `Y` values:

```
   int[] Xs = Z
     .Select(item => item.Item1)
     .ToArray(); // if you want them as array

   int[] Ys = Z
     .Select(item => item.Item2)
     .ToArray(); // if you want them as array
```

**Edit:** if you want remove an item from `Z` it looks as if you removing the both from `X` and `Y`:

```
   Z.RemoveAt(0); // let's remove the 1st item    

   Z.RemoveAll(pair => pair.Item2 < 5); // let's remove all y < 5 items

   // Let's have Y with 1st item deleted and all items < 5 removed
   int[] Ys = Z
     .Select(item => item.Item2)
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Could I remove numbers from X and have them also be removed from Y?

Comment: @lynxcs: yes, just remove `Tuple<int, int>` from `Z`. In case you want to *remove*, *add up* you probably should use `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()` when creating `Z`

Comment: Could I remove specific numbers? e.g. I select a Y of 5 and I want to remove everything that has a Y less than 5 (and also have it remove the X's related to those Y's)

Comment: I just noticed that if I declare the int's X,Y then it says that int doesn't contain a declaration for zip, but if I don't declare them then it says that X and Y doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: @lynxcs: do not forget to add `using System.Linq;` since `Zip` is an extension method.

Comment: @lynxcs: use `Z.RemoveAll(...)` to remove specific items

Comment: Hi, Everything seems to be working except for removing things. It just does nothing, could it be because Xs & Ys is an array? Could help me with this?

Comment: @lynxcs: `Z` doesn't change either `X` or `Y` initial arrays. You have to obtain `X` and `Y` from `Z` like `Y = Z.Select(item => item.Item2).ToArray();`

Comment: Ah, thanks! You've been a great help.

Comment: One last short question: How could I get amount of list items in a list? e.g: Z is: (500,200) (300,400) (200,800) so the amount of list items would be 3

Comment: @lynxcs: Lists (unlike arrays with `Length`) use `Count` property: `Z.Count`

Answer (score 1):

As you're new to C#, most would actually use objects for that rather than using two separate arrays. Something like this:

```
public class Point{
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    // This is a constructor - It's so you can use new Point(x,y);
    public Point(float x,float y){
        X=x;
        Y=y;
    }

}
```

Then you have an array of `Point` objects instead:

```
Point[] points=new Point[]{
    new Point(9,7),
    new Point(2,5),
    new Point(4,3)
};
```

Sort that based on the value of a particular field:

```
Array.Sort(points, delegate(Point a, Point b) {
    return a.X.CompareTo(b.X);
});
```

There's many other ways of sorting arrays (LINQ, List.Sort etc), but this is probably the easiest place to start from.